# What are the differences between Pokemon X and Pokemon Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y, version-differences

I want to know what are the differences between version X and Y, like pokemons, places, items, megaevolutions, etc.

Answer (score 30):

### Pokemon Exclusive to Version X

- Mega Charizard X
- Mega Mewtwo X
- Staryu/Starmie
- Pinsir
- Houndour/Houndoom
- Poochyena/Mightyena
- Aron/Lairon/Aggron
- Sawk
- Swirlix/Slurpuff
- Clauncher/Clawitzer
- Xerneas

### Pokemon Exclusive to Version Y

- Mega Charizard Y
- Mega Mewtwo Y
- Shellder/Cloyster
- Heracross
- Larvitar/Pupitar/Tyranitar
- Electrike/Manectric
- Purrloin/Liepard
- Throh
- Spritzee/Aromatisse
- Skrelp/Dragalge
- Yveltal

**Source** - [Serebii](http://www.serebii.net/xy/exclusives.shtml)

It's also been noted that there are minor story differences:

> Without giving away too much, both legendaries do end up having an impact on the story, so it's a matter of preference as to which one you want to see.

**Source**: [Shack News](http://www.shacknews.com/article/81541/pokemon-x-or-y-which-one-to-choose)

As always the main thing you should consider when choosing between Pokemon X and Pokemon Y is which version exclusive Pokemon appeal to you the most.

Comment: wow, +1 for pointing out the story differences also, everything counts, keep editing your answer for more information!

Comment: I saw too many Throh being used from a lot of npc trainers, sure it is exclusive?

Comment: @JoeCabezas yup, certain. NPC's aren't bound by version exclusivity as Game Freak aren't trying to make a quick buck through them ;)

Comment: That is very stupid. You get Tyrantiar in Y, but ( I did research) Tyranatarite is in X, and vise versa with Agron

Comment: Just commenting on the last paragraph to the answer, you could just wait to see if the Hybrid version of X and Y comes out like with Diamond and Pearl = Platinum, Blue and Red = Yellow

Comment: "As always the main thing you should consider when choosing between Pokemon X and Pokemon Y is which version exclusive Pokemon appeal to you the most." And which versions your friends have. If everybody you know has X, get Y. You can trade all the exclusives from them, and they will all want exclusives from you.

Answer (score 2):

The main Difference are the 2 main legendaries, Xerneas for X and Yveltal for Y.
There are also differnt mega evolutions for certain ones, like Mega Charizard X, Mega Mewtwo X and Mega Tyranitar (to name a few) for only X, while Mega Charizard Y, Mega Mewtwo Y, and Mega Gengar(again, just to name a few) only for Y.
Hope this helps. Oh, i have some more. Mega Aggron, Swirlix, Slurpuff can only be found in pokemon X. Spritzee and Aromatisse can only be found on Pokemon Y.