# What are the differences between the Battlefield series and the Bad Company series?

Tags: battlefield-series, battlefield-bad-company-series

I entered the Battlefield universe with *Battlefield 3*, but since then I read and heard that *Battlefield 3* and *Battlefield 4* were largely similar to the Bad Company series, specifically that DICE "should go back to *Bad Company*" - implying they like it much more than the *Battlefield* main series.

Seeing how people clearly feel the *Bad Company* series is superior, I'm curious as to what are the main differences between these series, what has been changed from one to the other in terms of, say, mechanics or setting? Is this just a personal preference or were there really some big changes made?

Comment: At least bother to leave a comment why you think this is an invalid question.

Comment: well I was in the middle of answering before it closed but whatever... ill just comment it: The destruction mechanics are different. in Bad company 2 you could essentially level an entire map, which Dice now wants to avoid (don't know why, probably has to do with flow of battle) so only certain things are destructible in the latest battlefield games. Another thing is that the bad company series was a side project for the game developers while work on the new frostbite engine was being done.

Comment: @JLaBella, thank you very much. All I needed was such an answer. It is a shame the question was put on hold "because it is too broad". I asked for basic differences, give me a break.

Comment: ran out of comment characters but had more: Also classes worked differently. Support class did not exist. Medics were a seperate class from assault had the LMGs while assault had assault rifles, C4, and ammo packs. Recons also had C4 as well has the ability to call in mortars. Engineers got the rocket launchers.

Comment: You're asking us to compare two different series; that's far too broad to be useful to anybody.  If you want to reopen it, please focus the question on a specific area you want to know about.  Asking about the whole game doesn't work.

Comment: thats the thing, though. its not 2 different series. they are both developed by the same company and the same exact style of game. For example, World at War and Black Ops(both Treyarch, of the call of duty series) are different games, but can still be easily compared and differentiated. If he asked the difference between CoD and Battlefiled then yeah, too broad as they ARE drastically different games.

Comment: @Frank, as a matter of fact, it would be very useful to me. I wasn't looking for a five page long answer. Just 4-5 core differences would suffice like JLaBella pointed out. If you ask me about core differences about BF and CoD, I could have listed 4-5 core differences even though they are developed by two DIFFERENT studios.

Comment: The point of questions is to help users in the future.  And answers should be complete and definitive.  Just because you'd accept a shorter answer doesn't mean it fully answers the question.  Arqade is about specific questions, not ones comparing two different series.  Even if they were made by the same company.

Comment: FYI, I voted to close it as primarily opinion-based as it seems like you're asking why people prefer Bad Company over the later Battlefields.

Comment: @3ventic, would you vote to open if I delete the "Why are people loving Bad Company so much?" part and leave only the "What are the main differences between these series?" part?

Comment: Yes, I would, because it's not too broad at all.

Comment: @Frank, what about this one? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/135459/what-are-the-differences-between-pokemon-x-and-pokemon-y These are two different series, would you vote to close that too? No, I don't think so.

Comment: @3ventic, done.

Comment: How can you even compare that as two different series?  You're being facetious.  Either way, it's the asker's responsibility to narrow down any sort of comparison question to a specific focus, as per our meta here: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2853/whats-the-difference-between-fortresscraft-and-minecraft-who-cares/4354#4354.  We *don't* compare two completely different series.  Please refine your question if you want it reopened.  That said, I'm done.

Comment: Thank you for your research, @Frank. Frankly, I should read that page to get a clearer view on the subject. Just one last question. Have you played those two series and which one do you prefer more? I am not being sarcastic or anything, please don't get me wrong.

Comment: @JLaBella as a sidenote: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160753/230957

Comment: @JLaBella This question has been currently reopened. You can now post your answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The destruction mechanics are different. In Bad Company 2 you could essentially level an entire map, which Dice now wants to avoid (don't know why, probably has to do with flow of battle) so only certain things are destructible in the latest Battlefield games.

Also classes worked differently. Support class did not exist. Medics were a separate class from assault and had the LMGs while assault had assault rifles, C4, and ammo packs. Recons also had C4 as well and the ability to call in mortars. Engineers got the rocket launchers.

Another thing is that the Bad Company series was a side project for the game developers while work on the new frostbite engine was being done. So it is essentially still a Battlefield game, but the developers had more freedom (as most of the team was busy with frostbite)

Comment: Bad Company also has a different tone for the single player.  Whereas Battlefield 3/4 is more like COD: Modern Warfare in terms of being serious, Bad Company has comedy (as well as destruction, as you have mentioned).  The cover art for Bad Company 1 pretty tells you what you are getting - a grenade with a smiley face.

Comment: @camelCase mentions a very important part being the tone. You know as soon as you start up BC1 that you're in for a treat...